# Error Closing VB Form - Unable to Cast "EventArgs" to "KeyEventArgs"

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have been working on a VB program that will help our internal operations, within this program i have created a form (Child Form) that takes some information and saves it into a database.

I have recently added the .KeyDown to my main box so that the user can hit enter rather than having to press a button. (See below for the header). (This is the first field you enter)

`Private Sub Model_Family_Validate(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtbox_modelfamily.Validated, txtbox_modelfamily.KeyDown`

On my Parent Form i have a log out button, that is `EventArgs`, if i enter my Child form and then log out it crashes saying

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'.`

If i remove my KeyDown event and the `Keyeventargs` to `Eventargs` it works fine.

- Even if i just enter this form and then log out it errors, i do not need to do anything in the child form.
- The reason i am using KeyEventArgs is because i need to know that the enter key has been pressed
- The Parent Form has a ribbon at the top with various buttons along with a drop down menu, containing further options. I am using one of the drop down options.

The other strange thing is i can press any other button apart from the log out.

```
Public Sub LogOff_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_m_logoff.Click

    Me.Close()
    frm_login.Show()

    frm_login.txtbox_loginpassword.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Can anyone see why it is doing this?

Any further information required then please let me know, Thanks.

Comment: you cant have one event handle both Validated and keyDown they events are simply different which is what the error is telling you.  What you **can** do is call a common procedure from each passing the relevant info.

Comment: Thanks for that, i have split them apart and it seems to have corrected the issue. Cant believe that was it...

Comment: The `Validated` event does not use `KeyEventArgs`. You cannot cast *down* an inheritance hierarchy unless the object is actually of that more derived type. At any rate, I strongly recommend *not* validating in response to a simple keypress. It can make keyboard navigation *extremely* tricky. Just use the `Validating` event; that's what it is for.

Comment: The Validation bit was to make sure that what was entered into the field existed in database. If you clicked out of the field without hitting enter you could then continue filling in the rest of the fields. I didnt want this, this field had to be validate first. I have made a some tweaks to my program to split these events out and its working fine now. So thank you both for your comments.

Comment: I also think that OPTION STRICT would flag that problem in the IDE rather than waiting for it to crash at runtime

Comment: I have set this, threw up some other things as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to log off when the enter button is clicked. You also have a button that says "Log off" that is supposed to perform the same function as pressing enter. If so, you should be using the `Me.AcceptButton` property of the form and set it to the existing log off button. You can either do this in the design mode or during runtime.

This property should then run the code in the `Private Sub Model_Family_Validate` sub-routine whenever Enter is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your answers, this issue is now fixed. I have turned Options Strict On and it has highlighted the issue, this has now been rectified.

I split the two events into their own sections and its now as i want.